# VB script to export to pdf in Command Button (ActiveX) in Word 2010

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010, export-to-pdf, commandbutton

Ok, so I have this Word 2010 Macro enabled template with my handy dandy forms that people can fill out. I have created a button that says "Convert to PDF" because people dont know how to do it natively. I entered the VB editor of the particular CommandButton that I want to have this functionality. Here's whats in that button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sub Convert_PDF()

 Dim desktoploc As String
 Dim filename As String
 Dim mypath As String

    desktoploc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    filename = ThisDocument.Name
    mypath = desktoploc & "\" & filename

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        mypath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
End Sub
```

When I run the code I get..... BAM! Compile error: Expected End Sub

If I take out the Sub Convert_PDF() and its pertaining End Sub, suddenly i dont get the sub error messages, but I get another error message:

`The file [file name] cannot be opened beacause there are problems with the contents. Details: The file is corrupt and cannot be opened.` Replace [file name] with my file's actual name.

I'll be completely honest, I'm a complete n00b at VB and Google is turning out to not being very helpful thus far :/

Any insight?

Comment: I think you need to create a PDF object. When I tried to do something like this years ago, they didn't have any free libraries to help with this. As a workaround (until I can see what I can find) you could print to a pdf printer and have your macro call that.

Comment: @Jeff - Excel 2010 has built-in save-as-PDF: no need for additional libraries...

Comment: You have two nested subs there - that's not valid VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Convert_PDF
End Sub


Sub Convert_PDF()

 Dim desktoploc As String
 Dim filename As String
 Dim mypath As String

    desktoploc = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    filename = ThisDocument.Name
    mypath = desktoploc & "\" & filename & ".pdf"

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        mypath, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=True, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: will try this out Tim, and let you know

Comment: Worked beautifully. Any way to append the a month that is selected from a drop-down form field? For instance, I have a drop-down where you can set the month... in the VBA for the button, I have created a string for user that is:

user = VBA.Environ("USERNAME")

I have changed the mypath string to:

mypath = desktoploc & "\Metrics\" & filename & " - " & date & " - " & user

now I just need to find out how to feed the info from the drop-down form into the Date string :/

Comment: Sorry - Word forms aren't something I'm familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

For your follow up question:

It depends on how you're picking your date.  If you're picking from a "Date Picker Content Control" then you'll need to follow the below code.  If you're picking from an Active X "combo box" then you'll need to pull it's value `[January]` from the dropdown box. `msgbox(DropDown.Value)` will show `"January`.  You could put it in an if statement if you need to convert the month to a number `[if DropDown.Value) = "January" Then...]`.

The below code is for getting the data from the "Date Picker Content Control" in word

```
'put this at the top of the code, outside any functions/subs
Dim DateGlobal As Date

'This sub will run whenever you exit any ContentControl function
Private Sub Document_ContentControlOnExit(ByVal ContentControl As ContentControl, Cancel As Boolean)
If IsDate(ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date").Item(1).Range.Text) = True Then
    DateGlobal = ActiveDocument.SelectContentControlsByTitle("Date").Item(1).Range.Text
End If

'Now use DateGlobal wherever you need it; it will be in date format.
msgbox(DateGlobal)                  'Shows date as default date format
msgbox(myDateFormat(DateGlobal)     'Shows date as your custom date format (below)
End Sub

'************************************************************************************
'                       Custom DATE format (instead of computer default)
'                       Found elsewhere on this site, I like my format yyyy/mm/dd
'************************************************************************************

Function myDateFormat(myDate)
    d = WhatEver(Day(myDate))
    M = WhatEver(Month(myDate))
    y = Year(myDate)
    myDateFormat = y & "/" & M & "/" & d
End Function

Function WhatEver(num)
    If (Len(num) = 1) Then
        WhatEver = "0" & num
    Else
        WhatEver = num
    End If
End Function
```